# Census data 5-year estimate for the United States

Tags: census, united-states

I am looking to download demographic data 5-year estimate based on census tract for the whole United States. The census website has the information, however, it does not let me to select the whole country based on census tracts along with the variables. Could you please advise?

Comment: I believe the data is broken up by state, so you will need to obtain the data for each state to build a national dataset.  There is an FTP setup for ACS data, http://www.census.gov/acs/www/data_documentation/data_via_ftp/

Answer (score 1):

Oh really, well if you are interested you could try this [geodatabase](http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER_DP/2012ACS/ACS_2012_5YR_TRACT.gdb.zip).